# Two Database Instances, need to share table data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wordpress, data

**Background**

Two sites, both WordPress; one is public-facing, and the second is private with restrictive access.

The public-facing site has a form on it, but I need to be able to access the information received from that form so that the private site can review it.

The form is built through a WordPress plugin.

Both databases live on the same server but are different instances and are managed through phpmyadmin.

Once the business logic is handled on the form, I don't need to retain the information on the public site and prefer that it get deleted from the table.

**Question**

Does anyone have a recommendation on how I can share information/transfer information to the private site database without losing functionality on either site?

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: If you are not writing to the public-facing tables, simply `JOIN` to those tables.